# Get JSON object before sent to template engine from openapi-generator?

Tags: openapi-generator

I am looking for a way to get the object generated from an openapi file via openapi-generate before it gets sent to the template engine.

By this i mean, the openapi-generator must 1st generate a big object to be passed to the moustache tpl engine (containing models, interfaces, request/response objects etc etc)... how can I get hold of this object?

Comment: Looks like you want heavily customize the output. Please open an issue via https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new/choose with the details on your use case so that the community can help you out.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/4502